# Netty: Add and Remove FrameDecoder dynamically from a Pipeline, Protocol encapsulation

Tags: java, netty

I've been working with Netty 3.3.1-Final for 3 weeks now.
My Protocol has 3 steps and each step needs a different **FrameDecoder**:

- Read arguments
- Transfer some data
- Mutual close of the data pipe

I've been through a lot of "blocking" issues that I could not understand. It finally appears to me, reading the **org.jboss.netty.example.portunification** example that I had some buffer issue when trying to **dynamically change my FrameDecoder**: the buffer of one FrameDecoder was (probably) not empty when changing for the next one...

Is there a way to do that easily in Netty? Do I have to change my Protocol? Do I need to write one big FrameDecoder and manage a state?
If so, how to avoid code duplication between different protocols with common sub parts (for instance "reading arguments")?

Today I came to the idea of a **FrameDecoderUnifier** (code below) with the purpose of a way to hot add and remove some **FrameDecoder**, what do you think?

Thanks for your help!

Renaud

----------- FrameDecoderUnifier class --------------

```
    /**
     * This FrameDecoder is able to forward the unused bytes from one decoder to the next one. It provides
     * a safe way to replace a FrameDecoder inside a Pipeline.
     * It is not safe to just add and remove FrameDecoder dynamically from a Pipeline because there is a risk
     * of unread bytes inside the buffer of the FrameDecoder you wan't to remove.
     */
    public class FrameDecoderUnifier extends FrameDecoder {

        private final Method frameDecoderDecodeMethod;
        volatile boolean skip = false;
        LastFrameEventHandler eventHandler;
        LinkedList<Entry> entries;
        Entry entry = null;

        public FrameDecoderUnifier(LastFrameEventHandler eventHandler) {
            this.eventHandler = eventHandler;
            this.entries = new LinkedList<Entry>();
            try {
                this.frameDecoderDecodeMethod = FrameDecoder.class.getMethod("decode", ChannelHandlerContext.class, Channel.class, ChannelBuffer.class);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            } catch (SecurityException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }

        public void addLast(FrameDecoder decoder, LastFrameIdentifier identifier) {
            entries.addLast(new Entry(decoder, identifier));
        }

        private Object callDecode(FrameDecoder decoder, ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Channel channel, ChannelBuffer buffer) throws Exception {
            return frameDecoderDecodeMethod.invoke(decoder, ctx, channel, buffer);
        }

        @Override
        protected Object decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Channel channel, ChannelBuffer buffer) throws Exception {
            if (entry == null && !entries.isEmpty()) {
                entry = entries.getFirst();
            }

            if (entry == null) {
                return buffer; //No framing, no decoding
            }

            //Perform the decode operation
            Object obj = callDecode(entry.getDecoder(), ctx, channel, buffer);

            if (obj != null && entry.getIdentifier().isLastFrame(obj)) {
                //Fire event
                eventHandler.lastObjectDecoded(entry.getDecoder(), obj);
                entry = null;
            }
            return obj;
        }

        /**
         * You can use this interface to take some action when the current decoder is changed for the next one.
         * This can be useful to change some upper Handler in the pipeline.
         */
        public interface LastFrameEventHandler {

            public void lastObjectDecoded(FrameDecoder decoder, Object obj);
        }

        public interface LastFrameIdentifier {

            /**
             * True if after this frame, we should disable this decoder.
             * @param obj
             * @return 
             */
            public abstract boolean isLastFrame(Object decodedObj);
        }

        private class Entry {

            FrameDecoder decoder;
            LastFrameIdentifier identifier;

            public Entry(FrameDecoder decoder, LastFrameIdentifier identifier) {
                this.decoder = decoder;
                this.identifier = identifier;
            }

            public FrameDecoder getDecoder() {
                return decoder;
            }

            public LastFrameIdentifier getIdentifier() {
                return identifier;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, having a frame decoder which *switch internal decoders based on some state* and *dynamically adding/removing upper layer handlers* should be avoided because

- Difficult to understand/debug the code
- Handlers are not having well defined responsibilities (That's why you are removing/adding handlers right? One handler should handle one or more (related) types of protocol messages, not many handlers same type of messages)
- Ideally frame decoder only extract the protocol frame, not to decode the frame based on state (here frame decoder can have internal chain of decoders to decoder the frame and fire a MessageEvent with decoded message, above handlers can react to decoded messages).

**UPDATE**: Here I have considered a protocol where each messages can have a unique tag/identifier with end of the message is clearly marked (for example [Tag Length Value](https://gist.github.com/1582634) frame format)

Comment: Hello @Jestan, let's imagine a shell application that would like to open an sub-shell application (just like what happens when you use ssh or switching from shell to bash...). Wouldn't you hot-plug a different FrameDecoder to do that? I use a state-based Protocol to save some bytes:
`RECEIVE A, if A==A0 RECEIVE B else RECEIVE C.` where A, B and C need 3 differents Decoders.
I suppose another and easier way to do this is to use one single unified Protocol with A as the header of a Token that could contain B or C... It leads to my second question: how to avoid code duplication??

Comment: It is OK to have multiple frame-decoders when you need to support multiple protocols, but in your case, you have only one protocol with multiple frame decoders (and some handlers added/removed based on received message type). If there is only one protocol to support, I think, the responsiblity of the frame decoder is "extract the frame regardless of message type or state" (in this case messages has to be encoded with identification tag or tlv format, and frame decoder can delegate the decoding to a chain of decoders to decode the extracted frame then fire a MessagEevent with decoded message)

Comment: Thank you for your help @Jestan!
Well we need a clear definition of **what is a protocol** here!
If I get you well, this is not a good idea to design a protocol where frame-decoding algorithm depends on an upper interpretation of the previously decoded frame. I understand that the states/steps I am handling in the upper handler should become a flag inside the Frame itself??
Meaning `Tokens A=[DATA] or B=[DATA] with FrameDecoderA and FrameDecoderB` should become `Token C=[AorB+DATA] with one single FrameDecoderC`, is that it? That's a little overall but could be simpler to implement?

Comment: You have got my point regarding decoding :), BTW I am not against having a state inside a decoder/handler,I was saying that, if the frame format of the protocol can have an identifier/tag in a header, you could have use a simple frame decoder to extract the frame A or B or C and have a message handler/handlers to receive them and react (of course, the handler receiving A,B and C has to have a state). P.S here frame means something like https://gist.github.com/1582634 . This will help to avoid removing/adding handlers (This line is the main point of my answer)

Comment: Okay @Jestan, I think we can close this question and I reword the answer. **Re-design you Protocol to have one unique frame-format** (meaning one unique method for re-assembling frames from the stream of bytes). You can always do this because dealing with different chained FrameDecoder is equivalent to inserting a "state" header in your frame and work with one single FrameDecoder!
I understand this is the way Netty is designed to work, it seems a bit painfull for re-usability of parts of the code.
Thank for your help @Jestan!
Regards,
Renaud

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar problems, in that removing a frame decoder from a pipeline does not seem to prevent it from being called, and there isn't an obvious way to make the decoder to behave as if it wasn't in the chain: Netty insists that the decode() reads at least one byte so you can't simply return the incoming ChannelBuffer, whereas returning null stops the processing of incoming data until the next packet arrives, stalling the protocol decoding process.

Firstly: the Netty 3.7 docs for [FrameDecoder](http://netty.io/3.7/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/frame/FrameDecoder.html) does in fact has a section "Replacing a decoder with another decoder in a pipeline".  It says:

> It is not possible to achieve this simply by calling
>   ChannelPipeline#replace()

Instead, it suggests passing the data on by returning an array wrapping the decoded first packet and the rest of the data received.

```
return new Object[] { firstMessage, buf.readBytes(buf.readableBytes()) };
```

Importantly, "unfolding" must have been enabled  prior to this, but this part is easy to miss and isn't explained.  The best clue I could find was [Netty issue 132](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/NETTY-132), which evidently gave rise to the "unfold" flag on FrameDecoders. If true, the decoder will unpack such arrays into objects in a way which is transparent to downstream handlers. A peep at the source code seems to confirm this is what "unfolding" means.

Secondly: there seems to be an even simpler way, since the example also shows how to pass data on down the pipeline unchanged. For example, after doing its job, my sync packet FrameDecoder sets an internal flag and removes itself from the pipeline, returning the decoded object as normal.  Any subsequent invocations when the flag is set then simply pass the data on like so:

```
protected Object decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
                        Channel channel, ChannelBuffer cbuf) throws Exception {

    // Close the door on more than one sync packet being decoded
    if (m_received) {
        // Pass on the data to the next handler in the pipeline.
        // Note we can't just return cbuf as-is, we must drain it
        // and return a new one.  Otherwise Netty will detect that
        // no bytes were read and throw an IllegalStateException.
        return cbuf.readBytes(cbuf.readableBytes());
    }

    // Handle the framing
    ChannelBuffer decoded = (ChannelBuffer) super.decode(ctx, channel, cbuf);
    if (decoded == null) {
        return null;
    }

    // Remove ourselves from the pipeline now
    ctx.getPipeline().remove(this);
    m_received = true;

    // Can we assume an array backed ChannelBuffer?
    // I have only hints that we can't, so let's copy the bytes out.
    byte[] sequence = new byte[magicSequence.length];
    decoded.readBytes(sequence);

    // We got the magic sequence?  Return the appropriate SyncMsg
    return new SyncMsg(Arrays.equals(sequence, magicSequence));
}
```

A decoder derived from LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder remains downstream and handles all subsequent data framing. Works for me, so far.